# Getting coordinates of circles in image

Tags: python, r, image, edge-detection

I'm trying to extract the coordinates of the center of curling rocks after they've been thrown ([Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlII5.png) and [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tDtR.png)), preferably saved as a .csv.

I've been using R, since I'm more comfortable with it, but a Python solution would be great if that works better.

My code is primarily based on these resources ([this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/pixsets.html#an-example-segmentation-with-pixsets) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html#blob-detectionextraction-of-local-maxima-denoising-scale-space)) but it's not working perfectly in terms of identifying the coordinates. I only want the big red/yellow circles (not the ones that are grouped at the top or bottom). I would rather not crop where the small rocks are, as I need the exact coordinates of the image for later on.

The current code is grouping some of the big rocks that are close together, like from the example 2, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoKOE.jpg), which makes the centers all wrong, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XHgD.jpg). So while it's usually finding the rocks, it's not getting them exactly, and therefore giving me the wrong coordinates.

I've put my code as well, but I'm not invested in the code - I am good with whatever solution works, in whatever language!

```
library(dplyr)
library(imager)
library(ggplot2)

im <- load.image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tDtR.png")
d <- as.data.frame(im)
m <- sample_n(d,1e4) %>% lm(value ~ x*y,data=.) 
im.c <- im-predict(m,d)
out <- threshold(im.c) 
plot(out)

df <- as.data.frame(out)

out <- clean(out,3) %>% imager::fill(7)

plot(im)
highlight(out)

df <- (out %>% label) %>%
  as.data.frame()

get.centers <- function(dt)
{
  dt %>% subset(value>0) %>% dplyr::group_by(value) %>% dplyr::summarise(mx=mean(x),my=mean(y))
}

centers <- get.centers(df)
plot(im)

points(centers$mx,centers$my)
```